# error java.net.socketexception permission denied

Tags: android

i am working with andriod2.2 while calling web service getting error like java.net.SocketException permission denied error ...already added the internet permission in andriodmanifeast file since getting error ....plz help me soon...............

Comment: Some more detail and a stacktrace and someone might be able to help you.